# how do i clear jquery click functions

Tags: jquery

I've got two buttons that both have hidden elements.

This is the basics of the HTML:

```
<button class="read">
<table class="displayReviews">
<button class="write">
<form class="writeForm">
```

There's some `js` to `toggle` the table and the form.

This is the `js`.

```
$('.read').click(function() {
    $('.displayReviews').toggle(),
    $('.displayReviews').css("position", "relative"),
    $('.writeForm').css("visibility","hidden");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.write').click(function() {
        $('.writeForm').toggle(),
        $('.writeForm').css("visibility","visible"),
        $('.writeForm').slideToggle("slow") ,
        $('.displayReviews').css("position", "absolute"),
        $('.displayReviews').css("top", "1000px");
    return false;
    });
});
```

I know this is a huge mess. If someone could just point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

I want it to display the form when the write button is clicked, and the table when the read button is clicked.

Comment: hey, is this what you want to achieve? http://plnkr.co/edit/NhLWFd1sGi1uVKg4QMNy?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.read').click(function() {
  $('.displayReviews').toggle("slow");
  $('form.writeForm').hide("slow");
});


$('.write').click(function() {
  $('form.writeForm').toggle("slow");
  $('.displayReviews').hide("slow");

});
```

try this way
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w6auLge/2/)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. I knew it was simple. I'm tired today.

Comment: looking on computer for so long will give a  toll on you have rest happy coding@tdrsam

Comment: Thanks @Pekka Week ends in less than three hours. No code for two whole days.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fiddle of what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/aL0djmju/

```
<button class="read">Read</button>
<table class="displayReviews"><tr><td>Table displayed</td><tr></table>
<button class="write">Write</button>
<form class="writeForm">Form displayed</form>

.displayReviews, .writeForm{ display: none;}

$(function(){
    $(".read").click(function(){
        $(".displayReviews").toggle();
        $(".writeForm").hide();
    });

    $(".write").click(function(){
        $(".writeForm").toggle();
        $(".displayReviews").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, what i did is,

1. I created a form, a table and two buttons.
2. Then i added css `display:none;` for both form and table.
3. On the click of the respective buttons, the content will be show by changing their css Display property to `block`

**JS code** :

```js
$('.read').click(function() {
    $(".displayReviews").css("display","block");
    $(".writeForm").css("display","none");
});

$('.write').click(function() {
    $(".writeForm").css("display","block");
    $(".displayReviews").css("display","none");
});
```

**CSS code** :

```
.displayReviews{
    display:none;
}
.writeForm{
    display:none;
}
```

**HTML code** :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="read">Read</button>
<table class="displayReviews">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table><br/>
<button class="write">Write</button>
<form class="writeForm">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id='name'/>
</form>
```

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
    <button class="read" >read</button>
<table class="displayReviews"  style="display:none;"><tr><td>table test</td></tr></table>
<button class="write">write</button>
<form class="writeForm" style="display:none;"><label> form toggle</label></form>
```

Set `display` to `none` on load and toggle it using jquery

```
$('.read').click(function() {
    $('.displayReviews').slideToggle(),
    $('.displayReviews').css("position", "absolute"),
    $('.writeForm').hide();
});



    $('.write').click(function() {

        $('.writeForm').css("visibility","visible"),
        $('.writeForm').slideToggle("slow") ,
        $('.displayReviews').hide();
        //$('.displayReviews').css("position", "absolute"),
      //  $('.displayReviews').css("top", "1000px");

    });
```